# ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID on localhost:8080 but NOT on localhost:3000, Why?

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssl, certificate, localhost

I properly (it seems) added a self-signed cert to chromium on ubuntu 18.04.

I am using docker, (laradock ~ php-fpm, nginx, mysql, redis, workspace) and I have added the certificate on nginx to the site I am running (nginx site's conf file), also added it on the workspace container (don't think it is needed there, but went ahead and added it anyways), also added it on my local machine, which is where I run `yarn start` from.

In the site I am locally running I am using a .test local domain mapped from localhost/127.0.0.1.

The certificate works, and adding it to the machine's and browser's store seems to have worked well also, as I no longer get the warning on the browser requiring one to either go away or click-through.

[image: Certificate is trusted.]

However, my local site is served through nginx (php/laravel) then using webpack it serves a vuejs app and some react components with hot-reload on the local serve. The stuff on webpack has been configured to use https and the certificates are being passed on the devServer configuration.

That part also seems to work... however... upon closer inspection... the https works for localhost:3000 but NOT for localhost:8080....

[image: Security Tab from Dev-Tools.]

I am not going into the details of how I generated the certificates, because it evidently works... where it has to, chrome trusts it... but not completely? I don't understand... What gives!?

So from localhost, both ports 8080 & 3000 are js apps served through node/webpack. They are using https and the output in the terminal definitely states the urls with https.

[image: Webpack terminal output]

I just can't seem to find out why this still errors out with `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

[image: Devtools console error loading app.js from localhost:8080]

I am so lost here...
I mean, can it really be invalid?
Why is it not invalid for port 3000?
Is this a problem with the certificate or is it how it's configured on webpack?

I apologize if I leave something out in the question...
I want to thank in advance for any help i can get. :)